# Vega lite: Line type mark discontinuous issue

Tags: javascript, charts, vega-lite, vega

My code is as follows:

```
{
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "width": 800,
      "height": 200,
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {
            "pre_120": 0,
            "pre_90": 0,
            "pre_60": 0,
            "post_60": 100,
            "post_90": 150,
            "post_120": 200,
            "type": "Mango",
            "count": "twenty"
          },
          {
            "pre_120": 0,
            "pre_90": 0,
            "pre_60": 0,
            "post_60": 90,
            "post_90": 140,
            "post_120": 190,
            "type": "Apple",
            "count": "ten"
          }
        ]
      },
      "transform": [
        {"fold": ["pre_120", "pre_90", "pre_60","0", "post_60", "post_90", "post_120"]}
      ],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "key",
              "sort": [
                "pre_120",
                "pre_90",
                "pre_60",
                "0",
                "post_60",
                "post_90",
                "post_120"
              ]
            },
            "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}
          }
        },
  {
    "mark": { 
      "type": "rule", 
      "color": "maroon", 
      "size": 3 ,
      "strokeDash": [6, 4]},
    "encoding": {
      "x": { "datum": "0" }
    }
  }
  ]
  }
```

Following is the link to the chart on Vega Editor.

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/5e4c2d4504be5cd555269faf042463db/discont_chart.json

I have manually added the 0 to the x-axis to to add a rule in the middle of the chart which is neccessary for my project. However, due to that, the rest of the line is now discontinuous. How could I solve this issue so the line is continuous?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "pre_120": 0,
        "pre_90": 0,
        "pre_60": 0,
        "post_60": 100,
        "post_90": 150,
        "post_120": 200,
        "type": "Mango"
      },
      {
        "pre_120": 0,
        "pre_90": 0,
        "pre_60": 0,
        "post_60": 90,
        "post_90": 140,
        "post_120": 190,
        "type": "Apple"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["pre_120", "pre_90", "pre_60", "post_60", "post_90", "post_120"]}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "key",
          "sort": [
            "pre_120",
            "pre_90",
            "pre_60",
            "0",
            "post_60",
            "post_90",
            "post_120"
          ],
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "pre_120",
              "pre_90",
              "pre_60",
              "0",
              "post_60",
              "post_90",
              "post_120"
            ]
          }
        },
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "color": "maroon",
        "size": 3,
        "strokeDash": [6, 4]
      },
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": "0"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The issue in this is that the 0 value is not known by me. It has been added only to denote to the user and to the left of it are the previous dates and to the right, the post dates. For the lines, the point joining should be only from 'pre_60' to 'post_60'

Comment: I see. You should add a scale domain then. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That worked! Thank you soo much! Could you please explain the logic behind the same?

Comment: A scale has a range and a domain. For instance, the x axis could have a range of the chart width and the domain could be [A,B,C]. You would be telling Vega to fit the domain values of ABC in the the width of the chart and space them evenly. You can read more  here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html